# Is it possible for a FOR LOOP cursor execute operations asynchronously?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursors

I was having a problem in which the number in a table isn't updated between each commit, it was supposed to be incremented 1 by 1 but it was been incremented 2 by 2, I included logs between the execution, and encountered that during the `for loop` the procedure was dealing with 2 "some_number" before even passing thought the place where it commits.

The structure in which I had the problem was like this:

```
create or replace procedure test_procedure(unique_code number) is

Cursor C01 is
    select  some_number,
            nvl(some_varchar_bool,'Y') some_varchar_bool
    from    some_place 
    where   some_code = unique_code;

begin

for r_c01 in C01 loop
    begin
    if  (r_c01.some_varchar_bool = 'Y') then
        first_procedure(r_c01_w.some_number); -- This one doesn't commit, selects a number to save in other table, and updates the number selected from that table by 1
        second_procedure(r_c01_w.some_number, 'varchar_word'); -- This one commits at the end
    end if;
    end;
end loop; --C01

commit;

end;
```

The 2 by 2 problem was resolved when I changed the `for loop` statement to the `open cursor` statement like this:

```
open C01;
loop
fetch C01 into
    some_number,
    some_varchar_bool;
exit when C01%notfound;
    if  (some_varchar_bool = 'Y') then
        first_procedure(some_number); -- This one doesn't commit, selects a number to save in other table, and updates the number selected from that table by 1
        second_procedure(some_number, 'varchar_word'); -- This one commits at the end
    end if;
end loop;
close C01;
```

So again I raise the question: Is it possible for this FOR LOOP cursor execute the "first_procedure" 2 times before executing the "second_procedure", that commits the changes?

Comment: _Is it possible_ -- yes if two caller procedures (what you represent with `test_procedure` in your contrived example) are running simultaneously.

Comment: I'm very surprised that there is any difference between the two approaches. If you have a test case that would be interesting.